# How to correctly assign properties for other properties in JObject?

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

What I am trying to achieve is converting a JObject to XML Document and then extract the outer xml from the XMl Document. Reasons behind this is to send the results as a push notification through Azure Notification Hub.

What I am trying to get is:

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text id="1">Message</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

What I have tried:

```
JObject notificationPayload = new JObject(
    new JProperty("toast",
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("visual",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("binding",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("@template", "ToastGeneric"),
                            new JProperty("text", notificationMessage,
                                new JProperty("@id", "1")))))))));
```

The above code is throwing an exception: `Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.` So what I have tried after is:

```
JObject notificationPayload = new JObject(
    new JProperty("toast",
        new JObject(
            new JProperty("visual",
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("binding",
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("@template", "ToastGeneric"),
                            new JProperty("text", notificationMessage,
                                new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("@id", "1"))))))))));
```

Above code gave me a result, but not the intended one. What I got was:

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>Message</text>
            <text id="1" />
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

To extract Xml From the JObject I am using the following method:

```
string jsonStringToConvertToXmlString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notificationPayload);
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonStringToConvertToXmlString);
return doc.OuterXml;
```

**Question: How could I give the id property to the same Text property?**

Comment: If your aim is to create XML, why use JObject at all? LINQ to XML would be a much better bet. You say you're trying to convert a JObject to XML, but your question really seems to be able *creating* the JObject. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to construct XML using JObject to save myself from writing the XML directly as a string. I didn't know about LINQ to XMl, I will check it now anyways. I just faced the problem I stated above.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did some search and thanks to you my life is easier now.. Hehe.. I used this `XElement notificationPayload = 
                new XElement("toast",
                    new XElement("visual",
                        new XElement("binding",
                            new XElement("text", notificationMessage, 
                                new XAttribute("id", "1")),
                            new XAttribute("template", "ToastGeneric"))));

            return notificationPayload.Value;`

Comment: Yes, I've added an answer to a similar effect. I'd suggest using `1` rather than `"1"` though, to get in the habit of letting LINQ to XML do conversions. It's very important for things like DateTime values :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, don't use a tool oriented at JSON to construct XML. If you already *had* JSON, it would make sense to use Json.NET to convert it to XML - but as you're building it from scratch, it's much cleaner to use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("toast",
        new XElement("visual",
            new XElement("binding",
                new XAttribute("template", "ToastGeneric"),
                new XElement("text",
                    new XAttribute("id", 1),
                    "Message"
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```